# what does the "no way" sign icon mean into VS watch pannel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

There is a scope icon in Visual Studio watches that I do not understand, 
it is the "no way" sign that is sometimes present over the property or field icon.
CF attached screenshot.

[image]
I did check on the doc of VS2015 icons and definitely do not see this "no way" sign:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx

What does it mean?

EDIT:
my property is declared as public:

```
public virtual DateTime? MyProp1 { get; set; }
```

And the sign is not present because of the virtual keyword because I have in this same class other auto-properties also declared as public virtual and the spy did not bother to add this "no way sign".
For instance:

```
public virtual MyType MyProp2{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I thought this one was obvious and would be answered in less than 2 minutes :)

Comment: I think that this means that the field is non public

Comment: apparently not, cf Edit

Comment: @A.D., Have not noticed it before, many of the encounters are lock icon, which means protected member. So, would you mind share us a simple sample so that we could reproduce this "no way" icon. I suspect it means the property or field is restricted or cannot be accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!
This apparently only occurs when the property is nullable

```
public DateTime? MyProp1 { get; set; } //there will be a "no way icon" when the property is instanciated
public DateTime MyProp2 { get; set; } //no "no way icon"
```

Still no idea why this icon is not listed in the MS documentation link in the original post...